# How to find out where a handler mapping is being inherited from in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, dotnetnuke

Here's my problem. I'm installing a module that the company I work for developed in a version 5.0.4 DotNetNuke installation.

The .dnn manifest file has a nodes section that includes this add

```
<node path="/configuration/system.webServer/handlers" 
    action="update" key="name" collision="overwrite">
    <add name="svc-Integrated" verb="*" path="*.svc"
     type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1111111111111111" resourceType="Unspecified" 
        preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</node>
```

The web.config for the DNN application does not already have this add in the configuration/system.webServer/handlers section so it adds it to the web.config.

Then when trying to load the web site, I get an error saying:

```
Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with 
    unique key attribute 'name' set to 'svc-Integrated'
```

I've spent some time looking for where this duplicate entry for svc-Integrated could be coming from, and finally found out to look in IIS at the Web Site the DNN web application is under. It has a section for *Handler Mappings*, and the svc-Integrated tag is in there for the web site, with an **Entry Type** of **Inherited**.

I'm trying to find out where the svc-Integrated handler is being inherited from.

Edit: I've looked through *c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG* at the *machine.config* and *web.config* files, and there are no entries at all that say "svc-Integrated" for the name. I tried looking in the *Framework64* folder and the v4.* folder under each at the *machine.config* and *web.config* and there are no svc-Integrated in **ANY** of those locations, so I don't have the slightest clue where IIS is getting this handler definition from :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Handler has an **Entry Type** of **Inherited**, you can find out where it is inherited from by going one level up in the *Connections* panel on the left-hand side of *Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager*, and double-clicking on *Handler Mappings* in the *Server Components* group. Find the same Handler on that level, and see if it is inherited from another level up, or if it is local to that level.

I found out that the handler mappings for the machine in IIS7 were coming from `"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config"`

[[This article]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754617(v=ws.10).aspx) on technet.microsoft.com helped me find the config file for the level I found the local entry at, and also explains the configuration inheritance levels.

*Machine.config. This file is located in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG.*

*Root Web.config for the .NET Framework. This file is located in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG.*

*ApplicationHost.config. This file is located in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config.*

That's where I found the svc-Integrated config entry I was trying to find.

I ended up just right clicking on the *svc-Integrated* handler mapping in my application's *Handler Mappings* and clicking Remove. This fixed the conflict my application was having with trying to overwrite the handler mapping.